# Chrome password check alert

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

I need to switch of Chrome password check alert. Because if I make an administration or login on localhost or if I log in to local database via chrome it always open this popup cause I have simple short passwords on my localhost. Is there a way to switch it off?

Chrome version is 84

Comment: What have you tried?  You don’t mention what version of Chrome your using (the location of the option has recently changed).  You should edit your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Comment: Chrome version is 84 (edited} but I really dont know why it alerts me always on localhost.... Thats the reason why I ask the question. I did not change anythins, it became with some update.

Comment: I assume you are storing the password in Chrome’s password manager?

Comment: Of course. But it is not the reason to see the alert every time.

Comment: This is so annoying, I don't really want to turn the password check off because it's very useful for the real stuff. But so much noise over localhost / 127.0.0.1 stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of version 84 Chrome does not allow to disable these leaked password check selectively for some domains or IPs. It is only allowed to disable these checks globally.

You can do that in `Settings -> Security`:

[image: option to warn about exposed passwords in chrome]

Because this is global for a person you can create a separate Chrome person and use it for accessing these local systems that do not require password checks.